RDS too many connections from Magento

Hi
I am facing an abnormal issue with RDS. Some times the sessions increases rapidly and eventually i need to restart the database. May be it is causing due to a lock on any table.
I still curious about this issue.
Any assistance will be highly appreciated.
Thanks
